# Comparability with zero of an ordered semigroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, order-theory, semigroups

Is it correct that any ordered semigroup $S$ can be embedded into an ordered semigroup with zero $S_0$ in which every element is comparable with $0$, in a way that the order of $S$ is a subset of the order of $S_0$?

If not, is it always possible to re-order an ordered semigroup in this way?

The question was moved from here: [Ordered semigroup with an absorbing element](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3737253/427611)

Comment: What do mean for the question on rings? Should $S_0$ be a subset of the ring ?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin I was thinking of $S_0$ as the same set as the ring itself. But it looks like any element is comparable with $0$ in an ordered ring by the definition, isn't it?

Comment: I don't think so. Take the equality as order.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I deleted the rings part since $\mathbb Z^2$ with $(a,b) \le (c,d) \iff a \le c \land b \le d$ is an example of a ring that is not comparable with $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the first question is yes.

Let $S$ be an ordered semigroup and let $S_0 = S \cup \{0\}$, where $0$ is a new zero element, that is, $0s = s0 = 0$ for all $s \in S_0$. Then the order on $S$ can be extended by adding the condition $0 < s$ for all $s \in S$.

Comment: Let's take your example in here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3739556/427611 and add an identity $1$ into it. Let's extend the order with $0 < 1$. So $a0 < a1$, $0 < a$. But $a < 0$. Contradiction. Am I missing something?

Comment: It just shows that you cannot extend the order with $0 < 1$.

Comment: But if I extend it with $1 < 0$, then $b1 < b0$, $b < 0$. Either way, $0$ is not comparable with $1$.

Comment: Yes, is that a problem?

Comment: Oh! You added another $0$! Got it.