# Comparability with identity of an ordered semigroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, order-theory, semigroups, monoid

It is possible to compare any ordered semigroup with $0$:
[Comparability with zero of an ordered semigroup](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3741247/427611)

Let's say an ordered semigroup $S$ is comparable with identity if it can be embedded into an ordered monoid $S^1$ in which every element is comparable with $1$, and the order of $S$ is a subset of the order of $S^1$.

Clearly, any totally ordered monoid is a semigroup comparable with $1$.

An ordered group $G(\bullet, e, \le)$ is comparable with identity if and only if it is totally ordered:

- $a \le b \iff e \le a^{-1} \bullet b$;
- $a \le b \iff e \le b \bullet a^{-1}$.

There is an example of a totally ordered semigroup that is not comparable with $1$: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3739556/427611

What would be the conditions for an ordered semigroup to be comparable with identity?

Comment: Why do you call it comparable? I think it would be more apt to call it "compatible".

Comment: Also, I'm confused --- why are you writing the group additively? A totally ordered group does not need to be commutative. If I recall correctly, the free group is totally orderable.

Comment: And besides, I don't understand where did rings suddenly come into the picture.

Comment: @tomasz I don't insist on the terminology. To me, more interesting is that adding $0$ into a semigroup is "natural", but adding $1$ is not.

Comment: @tomasz I updated the statement for groups and removed the statement for rings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there is no answer so far, here is a small observation related to your question.

Let $M$ be an ordered monoid and suppose that, for each $x \in M$, $x \leqslant 1$. Note that this is a stronger condition that just requiring that every element is comparable with $1$. I claim that in this case, $M$ is ${\cal J}$-trivial, which means that the [Green's relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_relations) ${\cal J}$ is the equality on $M$.

Suppose that $x \leqslant_\mathrel{\cal J} y$. By definition, there exists $u, v \in M$ such that $x = uyv$. Since $u \leqslant 1$ and $v \leqslant 1$, the condition  $x = uyv$ implies $x \leqslant y$.
Now, if $x \mathrel{\cal J} y$, then by definition $x \leqslant_\mathrel{\cal J} y$ and $y \leqslant_\mathrel{\cal J} x$, whence $x \leqslant y$ and $y \leqslant x$ and finally $x = y$.

Since a subsemigroup of a ${\cal J}$-trivial monoid is also ${\cal J}$-trivial, it follows that a semigroup which is not ${\cal J}$-trivial cannot be embedded in a monoid $M$ in which $x \leqslant 1$ for all $x \in M$.

A (difficult) result states that a finite monoid is ${\cal J}$-trivial if and only if it is a quotient of a finite monoid $M$ in which $x \leqslant 1$ for all $x \in M$, but unfortunately, I have no such result to offer for submonoids.

Comment: A comment: if $S$ is a monoid and identity is comparable to each element, then $S$ can be split into two monoids $S_{\leq 1}$ and $S_{\geq 1}$ (intersecting at $1$). So your remarks provide a necessary condition: if $S$ is comparable with identity, then $S=S_1\overset{\leq}\cup S_2$, where $S_1,S_2$ are $\mathcal J$-trivial monoids with possibly one element in common. It seems sensible to ask whether this is a sufficient condition.